# VueJS / Bootstrap vue - accordion broken on deployment

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-vue, bootstrap-accordion

I am facing difficulties with my VueJS deployment. I have an accordion based on this : https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/collapse#accordion-support

Everything works perfectly on my local project but when deployed on Netlify, it seems that the accordion is completely broken, first tab open and clicks on others dont trigger anything.
There is nothing appearing in my console.

I wonder if I need to include jQuery or Bootstrap in my app or bootstrap Vue is supposed to make them useless ?

Thanks

Comment: `Bootstrap-Vue` does not require `jQuery` or `Bootstrap.js`, but relies on `bootstrap.css` for most styling, so make sure you're including that. Based on [this issue](https://github.com/bootstrap-vue/bootstrap-vue/issues/5352)  there might be problems with the accordion in version `2.14.0`. Could you try locking your project to BootstrapVue `2.13.1`?

Comment: Make sure your `<b-button>` (which has v-b-toggle directive) doesn't have `href="#"` set.

Comment: Awesome guys, I tried both at the same time and now it's working perfectly !
Thanks